# C program to see in-memory representation of integer

Tags: c, pointers

I wanted to know what an integer looks like in memory (not just convert an integer to binary) so I wrote a little C program that takes an integer from the commandline and then points a pointer at each of the four bytes of a typical C 32-bit integer, and get its hex value.

This works nicely for positive integers. Once you enter a negative integer, however, you get funny output, as if the hex pointer no longer knows what to do:

```
$ ./int2bin 1
Binary representation of 1 is:
01000000
$ ./int2bin -2
Binary representation of -2 is:
fffffffeffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

My code follows below. I'm new to C so what I'm trying to do is probably very naive if not plain wrong. Could use a few ..hints though.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* int2bin(int x) {
    char *y = (char *) &x;
    char *returnString = malloc (sizeof(char) * 33);

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {  // increase the pointer to the next byte at every iteration
        sprintf(returnString, "%s%02x", returnString, *(y+i));  // get the hex value for the data under the pointer
    }

    return returnString;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("No arguments entered\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int x = atoi(argv[1]); // convert argument to integer

    printf("Binary representation of %d is:\n", x);
    printf("%s\n", int2bin(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why exactly 33 here? `char *returnString = malloc (sizeof(char) * 33);`

Comment: In memory, there are no _negative signs_, but there is a special meaning for the most significant bit for signed variable types, i.e. a `1` in that position indicates a negative value.

Comment: `sprintf(returnString, "%s%02x", returnString, *(y+i));`  Source and destination may not overlap: you cannot write to the buffer that you are reading from. Also `malloc(1+CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) )`

Comment: @wildplasser I think he is appending the 2 chars after returnString

Comment: He'll at least overwrite the NUL character. Anyhow: not allowed.

Comment: thanks; my rationale for 33 was to allow for the 32 chars of the hex representation of a 32-bit integer + NUL. I also noticed any value there works but understanding `malloc` will be for another time :). As for the `sprintf` to itself: I wanted to use a loop but didn't know enough C to do this.

Comment: @bluppfisk: Here's a hint: `sprintf` (indeed, all the printf variants) returns the number of bytes it wrote, not including the NUL terminator. Use that to track progress in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `*(y+I)` to `sprintf`, it gets promoted to a wider integer. In particular, this will cause a sign extension which causes bytes greater than 0x80 to be prefixed with a bunch of ff's in hex. This can be resolved by making `y` of type `unsigned char`, which means that it will be zero-extended rather than sign-extended:

```
unsigned char *y = (unsigned char *) &x;
sprintf(returnString, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", *(y), *(y+1), ...);
```

All the other instances of `char` can remain `char` and don't need to be made unsigned.

You can also use a mask:

```
sprintf(returnString, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", 0xff & *(y), 0xff & *(y+1), ...);
```

Comment: Note: there is still a `%s` in your format straing.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works, however I will need to read up on how sign extension works. Is there a way to not use the mask, and just get the literal byte of data each time?

Comment: @bluppfisk The issue isn't getting the literal byte; the issue is passing it to `sprintf` and friends. The use of `0xff &` simply lets us control the resulting `int` that we get from the promotion, by masking away any of the bits that get wrongly set as the byte is widened to an integer.

Comment: @bluppfisk Actually there's an easier way: Just use an `unsigned char` instead of a `char` when casting. I'll write up the edits now.

Comment: the unsigned char method didn't work for me. Only the mask did. However, I do think I begin to understand the integer widening thing: the hex pairs representing negative numbers are entirely different from those for positive numbers. Correct? I don't know why sprintf cannot handle that, though, as I am still just asking for the hexadecimal representation of a byte.

Comment: @bluppfisk It's not sprintf failing to handle it. It's that your expectations are distinct from the reality. If I have a number like 511 (0x1ff), it has bytes 0xff 0x01 0x00 0x00. When each of those bytes is converted to an integer by widening, it gets sign-extended. 0xff, when considered on its own, is negative (it's a `char` with value -1), so it gets sign extended to int `-1` which is 0xffffffff. `sprintf` is handling what it gets just fine (and it gets it as a result of following C language specifications), but you are expecting it to receive something else.

Comment: ah and it is converted to an integer because that's what %x implies (convert to int then alphanumeric representation)? Is there a way not to convert it to an integer but directly to its textual representation? Or am I off track here? I noticed `%c` does what I want but then I need a hex editor of course.

Comment: @bluppfisk It's always converted to an integer, due to limitations of how parameters can be passed to functions. It just happens that `%c` only considers the lowest eight bytes of the integer that it received when the incoming char got promoted.

Comment: Excellent. I think I sort of understand now. Got it working with your method now (I forgot to also intitalise *y as unsigned char). Marking as answer :) @i486's below is a nice write-out as well.

Comment: @wildplasser fixed, just saw your comment as it got buried beneath the other comments yesterday

Answer (score 2):

If you used "unsigned char *" for 'y', that would fix your signed integer issue. 
 Also, your way of generating 'returnString' is a bit inefficient since you repeatedly write the previous string back over itself on each loop through the 'for' loop.  This should address both issues:

```
char  *int2bin( int x )
{
    unsigned char  *y;
    char           *returnString;
    char           *retPtr;
    int            i;
    char           *hexDigits   = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    y = (unsigned char *) &x;
    returnString = malloc (sizeof(int) * 2 + 1);

    if (returnString != NULL) {
        retPtr = returnString;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
            /* Strip off the high order nibble of the byte and the bits
               right to get a value of 0 to 15.  Use that to index into
               the hexDigits string to get the associated hex digit for
               that value, storing it in the next returnString position. */
            *retPtr = hexDigits[(y[i] & 0xF0) >> 4)];

            /* Position the pointer into the returnString to where the
               next hex digit needs to be placed */
            retPtr++;

            /* Strip off the lower order nibble of the byte (which is
               already in the range of 0 to 15.  Use that to index into
               the hexDigits string to get the associated hex digit for
               that value, storing it in the next returnString position. */
            *retPtr = hexDigits[y[i] & 0x0F];

            /* Position the pointer into the returnString to where the next
               hex digit or the terminating NULL character needs to be placed */
            retPtr++;
        }

        /* Add a trailing NULL character to terminate the generated string */
        *retPtr = '\0';
    }

    return (returnString);
}
```

Or, if you really want to use sprintf, then this:

```
char  *int2bin( int x )
{
    unsigned char  *y;
    char           *returnString;
    char           *retPtr;
    int            i;

    y = (unsigned char *) &x;
    returnString = malloc (sizeof(int) * 2 + 1);

    if (returnString != NULL) {
        retPtr = returnString;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
            retPtr += sprintf(retPtr, "%02X", y[i]);
        }
        *retPtr = '\0';
    }

    return (returnString);
}
```

Either way, remember to 'free' the return string after you use it in the calling routine, otherwise you will have a memory leak.  A better solution might be to pass the buffer that is to be used to receive the string as a parameter, while also returning that address in the return statement.  That way, it could still be called from within another function call (e.g. 'printf').  Something like this:

```
char  buffer[sizeof(int)*2 + 1];
int   x;

x = 12345;

printf("Converting %d -- %s\n", x, int2bin(buffer, x));
```

For what you're doing here though is basically a hex dump of a memory location.  As such, a generic HexDump function might be more useful since it could be used
for any size data area, not just an integer.  For example:

```
char  *HexDump( char *buffer, void *data, int dataSize )
{
    char           *bufferPtr;
    unsigned char  *dataPtr;
    int            i;
    char           *hexDigits   = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if (buffer != NULL) {
        bufferPtr = buffer;
        dataPtr = (unsigned char *) data;
        for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            *bufferPtr = hexDigits[(dataPtr[i] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
            bufferPtr++;
            *bufferPtr = hexDigits[dataPtr[i] & 0x0F];
            bufferPtr++;
        }

        *bufferPtr= '\0';
    }

    return (buffer);
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
char  buffer[sizeof(int) * 2 + 1];
int   x;

x = 12345;
printf("Converting %d to hex -- %s\n", x, HexDump(buffer, &x, sizeof(x)));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I wanted to edit this again to mention a more generic solution of a HexDump routine, but for some reason, the system thinks I'm spamming it after re-editing this answer a few times to correct typos and add additional info.

Answer (score 2):

My edition to your function:

```
char * int2bin(int x)
{
    unsigned char *y = (unsigned char *) &x; // char may work but logically %02X format is unsigned
    char * returnString = malloc( sizeof x * 2 + 1 ); // 33 is too much (16 bytes long int type?)

    returnString[0] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof x; i++ )
    {
        sprintf( returnString + strlen( returnString ), "%02X", y[i] );  // get the hex value for the data under the pointer
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic the argument should be `(unsigned int)y[i]`, it's technically undefined to use `%x` with any argument type besides `unsigned int`. The other answers all have the same issue too .

Comment: A slight optimization is possible, `returnString + i * 2` rather than re-computing `strlen` each time

Comment: @M.M I agree. About `%x` and byte parameter - there was a rule that byte parameters are extended to `int/unsigned` in stack (if I remember correctly).